# check quantity in check boxes validation javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Recently I posted a query about why my javascript form wasn't working.  One of the three issues was - The check boxes and quantity

I need to test each input value using my chkquantity regular expression and make sure that more than zero have been ordered as currently my code only checks for cases where a checkbox has been checked but no quantity supplied or a quantity supplied but it's checkbox not checked and therefore these tests do not preclude a submission with no checkboxes checked and all quantities set to zero.

I then need to generate an further test for totqty being less than or equal to zero

regular expression -
        var chkquantity = ^([1-9]?\d|[1-4]\d{2}|500)$/

tests

```
if (((document.form1.summer.checked) && (summer2012 <=0)) 
|| ((document.form1.autumn.checked) && (autumn2012 <=0)) 
|| ((document.form1.winter.checked) && (winter2012 <=0)))
{ 
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please enter Quantity" +"\n"; 
}
else if (((!document.form1.summer.checked) && (summer2012 >0)) 
|| ((!document.form1.autumn.checked) && (autumn2012 >0)) 
|| ((!document.form1.winter.checked) && (winter2012 >0))) { 
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please choose Product" +"\n";
}

if (alertmsg != "")
{
alertmsg = "Please enter the following values \n" + alertmsg;
alert(alertmsg);
} 

var f = document.form1;
if (!f.summer.checked && !f.autumn.checked && !f.winter.checked) {
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please choose at least one edition of the magazine" +"\n";

}

if ((chkquantity.test(quantity) <= 500) {
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please limit each magazine to 500 copies or less:" + "\n";
}
```

html -

```
 <form name="form1" method="post">
    <fieldset id="fieldset">
       <legend id="legend">Order the latest Saraysounds Magazine</legend>
 <table width="500" border=0 align="left" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
           <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div align="left">First Name</div></td>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="fname"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div align="left">Second Name</div></td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="lname"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div align="left">Address</div></td>
          <td colspan="2"><textarea name="address" cols="30" rows=5 col=40 wrap=soft>    </textarea>
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td colspan="2"><div align="left">Postcode</div></td>
          <td colspan="2">  <input type="text" name="postcode"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div align="left">Email</div></td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><div align="left">Telephone</div></td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="telephone"/>
          </td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                 <td colspan="4"><center>
                   <strong>Select Magazine</strong></center></td>
                 </tr>
                     <tr>
                 <td width="123"><center>
                 <strong>Product Name</strong></center></td>
                 <td width="30" ><center>
                   <strong></strong>
                 </center></td>
                   <td ><center>
                   <strong>Price</strong>
                 </center></td>
                   <td>
                  <strong>Quantity</strong>
                 </td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
             <td  align="right">Summer 2012
               </td>
             <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="summer" value="Summer 2012"/>
           </td>
             <td align="center" width="69"><div align="right">20.00 </div></td>
             <td width="216"><input name="summer2012" type="text" size="5"   value="0"/></td>
               </tr>
         <tr>
             <td align="right">Autumn 2012
             </td>
             <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="autumn" value="Autumn 2012"/>
           </td>
             <td align="center" width="69"><div align="right">20.00 </div></td>
             <td><input name="autumn2012" type="text" size="5" value="0"/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td align="right">Winter 2012
           </td>
             <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="winter" value="Winter 2012"/>
          </td>
             <td align="center"  width="69"><div align="right">20.00</div></td>
             <td><input name="winter2012" type="text" size="5" value="0"/></td>
          </tr>
               <tr>
             <td align="center" colspan="4"><input name="button" type="button"   onClick="javascript:display()" value="Submit"/>
              <input type="reset" value="Clear Form"/>
             </td>
           </tr>
  </table>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Posting the HTML that goes along with this javascript code would be helpful.

Comment: I need to check that more than zero have been ordered and apparently the test isn't appropriate for this